# Javascript/Html stop text wraparound

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to output lines to a text box in a webpage. Some of the lines are very long. Lines which are too long to fit should cause a scrollbar to appear as necessary.

If the string is too long, it wraps around in the text box instead of overflowing to the right and opening a scroll bar.

Html:

```
<pre class="form-group" style="border:1px solid black;overflow:scroll;height:200px;width:100px">
    This is a lot of text foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
</pre>
```

The width is set to 100px here to demonstrate but will have to be set to the full width of 100% in the application. How do I stop these wraparounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent the text from wrapping use `overflow: scroll !important;`

The `!important` forces the overflow state if you have conflicting styles.

Comment: My text is wrapping onto the next line, instead of creating an side scroller overflow. That's the problem.

Comment: I added the !important and I still see wraparound. How could my document be breaking this?

Comment: Please add more code or a link to the page in question if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Using the white-space-n:nowrap attribute fixed the problem for my project. JSFiddles posted by Webber and spencerLarry work fine outside of my particular project.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much got it right.

Try using css:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Shown in this link:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krum79rv/)

Comment: I've tried that. The JSFiddle works as expected. Yet when I copy the exact JSFiddle into my html even, and it still wraps around. I'm not sure why. Maybe the CSS is referring to pre or form-group and also setting attributes? Why would that work in a js fiddle but not when cut and pasted into my html?

Comment: What Doctype are you using? Also; is there any css overriding it? If it works in JSFiddle, it works as expected and there is something wrong with the piece of code that you paste it in.

Comment: this is not the problem, `overflow: scroll;` also works in your fiddle

Comment: The problem is not in the code then. But in your page. I've also tried it in a blank page with <!doctype HTML> Also, if !important fixes your problem then you have conflicting css. And my answer is still valid.